# Example of a Picard stack

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, picard-group

Let $F$ be the stack (over some base scheme $S$) which associates to every scheme $X$ the groupoid of invertible sheaves on $X$. Then by the general theory (see for example [Aoki's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503358)) $F$ is algebraic. My question is: Can you write down a nice presentation $P \to F$ explicitly, i.e. a surjective smooth morphism from a scheme $P$?